# java - break loop with invalid input

Tags: java, while-loop

I am creating a program that calculates users grades based on their input. All is good except that I need to deal with users inputting invalid entries.

Example: The user enters three exam scores on a single line (95 90 87 for example). If one of these scores is negative (95 90 -87) I need the program to NOT enter those three scores and assign a letter grade and instead prompt the user to re-enter the scores correctly.

Here is my code:

```
public class GradeCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int classSum = 0;       // variable used to hold sum of entire classes exams
        int classExams = 0;     // variable used to hold number of exams taken by whole class

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to Gradecalculator!");
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of students:");
        int students = s.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of exams:");
        int exams = s.nextInt();   

        int i = 0;
        int studentnumber = 1;
        int sum = 0;

        while (i < students) {    // loop until it matches number of students entered above
            i++;
            sum = 0;

            System.out.println("Enter student " + studentnumber++ + "'s name :");
            String studentname = s.next();

            System.out.println("Enter exam scores :");

            int input = 0;
            for (; input < exams; input++) {   
                int n = s.nextInt();
                sum+=n;

                if (n < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid exam scores, reenter: ");  //if one of the scores entered is     negative, display message
                }
            }

            double average = sum/exams;        // assign letter grade based on average of exams
            if (average <= 100 && average >= 90) {
                System.out.println("Letter grade: A");
                System.out.println(studentname + " gets 4 stars! ****");
            } if (average <= 89 && average >= 80) {
                System.out.println("Letter grade: B");
                System.out.println(studentname + " gets 3 stars! ***");
            } if (average <= 79 && average >= 70) {
                System.out.println("Letter grade: C");
                System.out.println(studentname + " gets 2 stars! **");
            } if (average <= 69 && average >= 60) {
                System.out.println("Letter grade: D");
                System.out.println(studentname + " gets 1 star! *");
            } if (average <= 59) {
                System.out.println("Letter grade: F");
                System.out.println(studentname + " gets 0 stars!");
            }

            classSum += sum;             // add sum of this student's scores to the classSum
            classExams += exams;   // add exams taken by this student to amount of exams taken by whole class
        }

        int classAverage = classSum/classExams; // compute class average
        System.out.println("Class statistics:");
        System.out.println("\tAverage: " + classAverage);
    }
}
```

Clearly I have this code in the wrong place:

```
                if (n < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid exam scores, reenter: ");  //if one of the scores entered is     negative, display message
                }
            }
```

Because this is the output I get when entering a negative score:

```
Enter exam scores :
70 70 -70
Invalid exam scores, reenter: 
Letter grade: F
joe gets 0 stars!
```

As you can see, it still assigns a letter grade and stars and asks for the next student's name. I need it to instead ask to re-enter this student's scores. Can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: As you see in both so far received responses and your comments to these, your question is not yet well stated. Please consider clarifying the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract one from the input inside that for loop so that it stays in that loop and other inputs aren't wiped out (and also make sure that the sum doesn't add those negative inputs)

```
int input = 0;
for (; input < exams; input++) {   
    int n = s.nextInt();
    if (n>=0)
      sum+=n;
    else {
        input--;
        System.out.println("Invalid exam score entered, reenter: ");  
     }

}
```

Comment: ok so I made this change and it's working except that instead of purging both scores a user enters (like -80 and 90) it only purges the negative score (-80) instead of both scores. how do I make it get rid of both values entered?

Comment: Yes, it won't purge 90 because 90 isn't an invalid input. So if you want to reset every score the user has entered, simply reset 'input' and 'sum' variables to 0 (and also let the user know in some way that scores have been purged).

Comment: but what if i only want to reset every score for that particular student (the one who entered the invalid score) and not students who entered scores before that? is that possible?

Comment: Yes, actually, what happens is that when you reset the scores while lets say studentNumber2 was entering inputs, that doesn't effect the inputs of studentNumber1 because they have already been displayed and processed (I think).

Comment: Yes you are correct regarding the previous processes, they would be already processed. That makes this a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Use interactive input, which should be more user friendly.

You need to reset your loop counter to start the loop again:

```
// Delete first output and counter variable initialization before loop
for (int input = 1; input < exams; input++) {   
    System.out.println(String.format("Enter %d. exam score: ", input + 1));

    int n = s.nextInt();

    if (n < 0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid value (must be positive)!");
        input--; // Reenter last value
    } else {
        sum+=n; // Only use correct scores.
    }
}
```

Comment: but if we're entering the third student's scores when we input a negative, wouldn't input=0 wipe the previous two student's scores as well?

Comment: Yes, I assumed that was what you want. Otherwise you decrease the counter... Updated the answer accordingly.